# Inserting html just before body of all pages (drupal 7)

Tags: theming

I want to add some html just before the start of body of all pages. I have managed to do so by adding the html before the body tags in html.tpl.php. It works fine. But it appears in all themes. I want it to appear only for my default theme (i.e. stark). How can I do that?

Comment: which html.tpl.php did you eidt?

Comment: The one in modules/system/

Comment: Please look at my answer. you would need to copy the file to your theme folder and edit it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be editing the template file with in the theme. By default stark does not have any template files. You should copy the required template file to the theme you are using and then edit the same there.

Comment: I know it should be solved using template files but so far I have been unable to do so. I have created a page.tpl.php but I cannot figure out what code will go inside. All the pages on my site are Page Display of Views instead of the Page content type.

Comment: you are right. I copied the html.tpl.php file in my theme folder and edited it. Works now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you should take a look at the other themes rather than stark. Stark is the very strip down version of a theme to understand how the output from drupal modules come. I think you should take a look at the zen theme http://drupal.org/project/zen. it has got a good structure and has all theme templates with in the template folder.